# javascript array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following arrays:

```
var dates = new Array();
var answers = new Array();
```

Once Populated, they will be the same length. What I need is an array that pair the same index values of the arrays. Like so:

```
var pairedArray = new Array();
//pairedArray should have the form: [[dates[0], answers[0]], [dates[1], answers[1]], ...., [dates[n-1], answers[n-1]]]
```

e.g.

```
data: [
            [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9], 
            [Date.UTC(2010, 2, 1), 71.5], 
            [Date.UTC(2010, 3, 1), 106.4]
        ]
```

How is this possible given that I have two arrays of the same length, answers and dates that are already populated?

Comment: i wouldn't do the inside as an array.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick - in general, `[]` notation is way more awesome than `new Array()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know they are always the same length, simply loop through one and add both to the result:

```
var data = [];

for(var i=0; i<dates.length; i++){
    data.push([dates[i], answers[i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = $.map(dates, function(v,i) { return [ [ v,answers[i] ] ]; });
```

---

You can use the [`jQuery.map()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method, but you need to double-wrap the returned Array because when `$.map` gets an Array, it performs a `concat`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstArray = ...
var secondArray = ...
if (firstArray.length === secondArray.length) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
        result.push({ [ firstArray[i], secondArray[i] ] });
    }
    // TODO: do something with the result
}
```

Comment: Don't think that will work with the `{}` unless you give the property a name `{something: [...]}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dates = new Array();
var answers = new Array();
var pairedArray = new Array();

$.each(dates, function(i){
   pairedArray.push([ dates[i], answers[i] ]);
});
```